# Hiding all products except for one in wordpress admin panel

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I just got very strange requirement from the client that he wants to hide all product from admin panel product tab except for one product **which has id 9** any one have any idea how to do that would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance. By the way I have tried it using css but logic doesn't make any sense I want the WordPress solution to do this.

Comment: Are you using Woocommerce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `pre_get_posts` hook to alter the WordPress main query.

`$query->get()` : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get/

`is_admin()` : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

`pre_get_posts` hook : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

```
// Handle the main query and set the post ID to 9
function wpse_288586_hide_products($query) {
    // We have to check if we are in admin and check if current query is the main query and check if you are looking for product post type
    if(is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get('post_type') == "product") {
        $query->set('post__in', array(9));
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_288586_hide_products');
```